# Is there a way to display div after li only with css?

Tags: html, css, printing, tabs

I have the following tabs structure:

```
<ul>
    <li id="first">First header</li>
    <li id="second">Second header</li>
    <li id="third">Third header</li>
    <li id="fourth">Fourth header</li>
</ul>
<div id="first_div">First content (related to first li)</div>
<div id="second_div">Second content (related to second li)</div>
<div id="third_div">Third content (related to third li)</div>
<div id="fourth_div">Fourth content (related to fourth li)</div>
```

On web view it displays correctly (with some simple script: displaying a div depending on selected li).

But on the print view this should be displayed in the following structure:

```
First header
First content

Second header
Second content
```

If I add `display: block` on the whole structure it apparently firstly displays `li`s, then `div`s.

Is there a way to form required view only with css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data-attributes` if it is just about to show a title .

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

```css
/* @media print { */

ul {
  display:none;
  }

div:before {
  content:attr(data-title);
  display:block;
  font-size:1.4em;
  margin:1em 0 0.25em;
  background:gray;
  }

/*}*/
div {
  background:lightgray;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="first">First header</li>
    <li id="second">Second header</li>
    <li id="third">Third header</li>
    <li id="fourth">Fourth header</li>
</ul>
<div id="first_div" data-title="My First Header title">First content <br/>(related to first li)</div>
<div id="second_div" data-title="My Second Header title">Second content <br/>(related to second li)</div>
<div id="third_div" data-title="My Third Header title">Third content <br/>(related to third li)</div>
<div id="fourth_div" data-title="My Fourth Header title">Fourth content <br/>(related to fourth li)</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

No, without duplicating content its not possible. However you can achieve this as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="headers-list">
    <li class="first">First header</li>
    <li class="second">Second header</li>
    <li class="third">Third header</li>
    <li class="fourth">Fourth header</li>
</ul>

<div class="first print-header">First header</div>
<div id="first_div">First content (related to first li)</div>

<div class="second print-header">Second header</div>
<div id="second_div">Second content (related to second li)</div>

<div class="third print-header">Third header</div>
<div id="third_div">Third content (related to third li)</div>

<div class="fourth print-header">Fourth header</div>
<div id="fourth_div">Fourth content (related to fourth li)</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.print-header {
    display: none;
}

@media print {
    .headers-list {
        display: none;
    }
    .print-header {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be selected as a solution, but in my project I have at least three tabs implementations and I want to achieve required objective with minimum html modifications.